# How to remove Toshiba computer laptop password?

Tags: toshiba-laptop

I have got a Toshiba Satellite M300 PSMS4L-03FOOC laptop which I have been using fine. Suddenly today a black screen appears, asking for a password, which has stopped me from using the computer at all. I Googled search for answers to my problem which I wondered how to apply suggestions!

I turned off the computer, turned it over and removed battery and put back in. I opened the computer but it didn't work. After more consideration I repeated this step and next removed the small frame next to the earphone plugin socket (and USB sockets). I pulled it out and put back in. Next I turned on the computer. Amazingly it opened up the normal screen but to the time 6 years ago - probably when the previous owner started using the computer. I next reset to the current time. I am glad that I can now use the computer again!

During the next time, I opened the computer again the password requirement came up again and I had to repeat the second process – removed battery + small black frame. It might work or not work again!

Comment: When did the black screen appear? Inside Windows or during boot?

Answer (score 0):

> Next I turned on the computer. Amazingly it opened up the normal
> screen but to the time 6 years ago - probably when the previous owner
> started using the computer. I next reset to the current time. I am
> glad that I can now use the computer again!

This all sounds to me like a CMOS battery issue or a BIOS password issue. How it appeared? Unclear. But I am pretty sure this is the case since you mention the system date going back to 6 years ago which is 2008 (2014 - 6 = 2008) and checking online review they seem to start to mention the Toshiba Satellite M300 starting in 2008. Toshiba has [a support site which lists different ways of initially setting the BIOS password](http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=108503), but doesn’t clearly state how to reset a BIOS password. But [this site explains in detail](http://www.technibble.com/how-to-bypass-or-remove-a-bios-password/) how to do it by removing the CMOS battery:

> The simplest way to remove a BIOS password is to simply remove the
> CMOS battery. A computer will remember its settings and keep the time
> even when it is turned off and unplugged because these parts are
> powered by small battery inside the computer called a CMOS battery. If
> we pull out this battery, the computer will forget alot of its
> hardware settings, including its BIOS password. This should not be
> performed on Laptops if you are not experienced working with laptop
> hardware.

[image]

> Anyway, open up the computer case using a screw driver and locate the
> flat, circular and metallic CMOS battery. It should look something
> like the picture to the right (NOTE: the picture is above in this
> answer) . Some computers have this part standing upright. Once you
> have located it, observe how the latches are holding it. There are
> many different ways to remove a CMOS battery but the most common way
> on newer computers can be seen in the picture below.

[image]

> **Removing the CMOS Battery**
>
> Make sure to power down the computer, unplug the power cables and
> unplug any USB devices if they are powered. The computer must not be
> able to get power from anywhere for this to work. Take out the CMOS
> battery and wait 10 – 25 minutes before putting it back in. The reason
> for this wait is because the computer can still store power in its
> capacitors even though everything is unplugged. The waiting period
> allows enough time for them to discharge.
>
> Plug everything back in, power up the computer and enter the BIOS
> again. If everything went well there should be no more password. In
> some cases, if you get weird error messages during bootup now, you
> will need to goto “Load BIOS Defaults” in BIOS and save the changes to
> fix them.